# DisplayMemberBinding when my ItemsSource is a List<string[]>

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I bind `DisplayMemberBinding` when my `ItemsSource` is a `List<string[]>` in my GridView?

**EDIT:**
Figured it out! No need to answer. (binded to [i], where i is array index)

Comment: Figured it out! No need to answer. (binded to [i], where i is array index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use-

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfStringArrays}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [0]}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [1]}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Column 3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [2]}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Did just figured it out my self. But will mark your answer correct. Thank you for answering!